# Android and SQLite - retrieve max id of a table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create a method to retrieve the max id of a specific table.

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
private long getMaxId()
{
    String query = "SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM mytable";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"max_id"});

    int id = 0;     
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {           
            id = cursor.getInt(0);                  
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());           
    }
    return id;
}
```

The exception being thrown is this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24624): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x200408
```

I suppose the problem is this line:

```
            id = cursor.getInt(0);
```

Does anybody have an idea of how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"max_id"});
```

with

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

From the [rawQuery description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery) , for the 2nd argument:

> You may include ?s in where clause in
>   the query, which will be replaced by
>   the values from selectionArgs. The
>   values will be bound as Strings.

Since you dont have any placeholders in your SQL query, maybe it is the source of the problem.